# Tuleap: display of project title

Tags: centos, tuleap

I created a new project with a quote in the title. However, in the title of the project Tuleap added a back slash just before the quote.

The title of my project is `Gestionnaire d'études`, and Tuleap registered `Gestionnaire d\'études`.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug you can report it in [Tuleap bug tracker](https://tuleap.net/plugins/tracker/?tracker=140)